# Hide tooltip with message in angular js with required field validator

Tags: angularjs, html

I need to show/hide a tooltip states of an input field: “This is a required field”. I am using a ng-required input tag.

```html
 <form novalidate  name="CustAddressDetails">
<input type="text" name="txtResAddressLine1"  id="txtResidentialAddress1" ng-model="Address1" ng-required="true" />
<span ng-show="ShowAddressErrorMsg && CustAddressDetails.txtResAddressLine1.$error.required">Please enter the Residential Address.</span>
</form>
```

Comment: can you able to post what you have tried?

Comment: S i did, but the tool tip is always populating need to be hide

Comment: post that code then only we can know what's the problem with that, or otherwise how can we know the issue what you have faced

Comment: just use a condition on the length of your model and you're good to go

Comment: I have updated my answer @Manojprabakar

Answer (score 1):

here I have removed `ShowAddressErrorMsg` because once your form is valid you need to change it manually

```js
     var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
        app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <form name="CustAddressDetails">
    <input type="text" name="txtResAddressLine1" id="txtResidentialAddress1" required ng-model="Address1" />
    <span ng-show="CustAddressDetails.txtResAddressLine1.$pristine || 
     CustAddressDetails.txtResAddressLine1.$untouched ||
       (CustAddressDetails.txtResAddressLine1.$touched || 
        CustAddressDetails.txtResAddressLine1.$invalid)">Pleas‌e enter the Residential Address.</span>
    <input type="submit"/>      
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: This isn't updated if you empty the field after typing something

Comment: i missed to mention `required` in input field

Comment: and I recommend you to use some validator for validation because everything is already available in that.  no need to concentrate on silly mistakes. like jquery.validator.js is really good, i already did it using that and i have attached link with this https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/PzBNBY